# The best way to manage database (ACCESS)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ms-access, report

What is the best way to organize a big database.

The way it works is that only I am allowed to touch or modify the database but interns help sometimes to collect data, we used to have the whole system excel based, back than we had the macro which by choosing 2 files it will integrate and mark in colors the changes.

How can I create something friendly to use which will update by pressing a button and also will show changes!! I am familiar with the update query, however:

it doesn’t track any changes.
I want to know other options.
To sum up the way of processing is:

I have the database and I need to split some data to smaller files so other employees will work on.

Then I will collect the files and integrate with the existing database, but since we are all human mistakes can happened that’s why I want to be able to track easily changes.

The updates are going to happen often. When I will give the intern a temp. table The possible changes are for example: address, phone number, price, they will do those researches based on current data which they will find online which information has been changed, and they will change the info which is on the temp. table, That is why I want to be able to know what exactly did they found out. Lets say if Product A (product ID1234) used to cost 10$ and today its 12$ from the same supplier. I just want to know and to see that the price for product ID1234 has been changed. Not only to have it updated to the back end database. For quality assurance I need to track which new input they did in relation to the product ID. (some times input by someone else which was done in wrong format or wrong column could affect big time on the quality of the reports)

So this was the explanation for what I need the reports

So in order to make those temp. tables, I want to create a form for it that by choosing region, category etc. and then clicking on a button it will automatically select the relevant records from the database, create a new table/access-file and then copy the selected records to the temp. table. So someone else could work on it...

Next thing is that it would be nice to know how can I create a template for tables, by template I mean to standardize by validation rules. some fields I'd like to have dropbox menu, some fields ready mask for phone number.... etc.

Final part, after they made the changes and saved the file (the temp. table which they were working on), I want to be able to update the back-end database via clicking on a button...

Looking forward to get the best solution!

Thanks in advance J

Michael

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.  The question you've posted is very broad.  It might be better to rephrase your question to ask the general approach questions (although this may be better on Superuser than here), and then dig into the technicals ONLY ONCE you've tried some stuff and have got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Okay for the temp tables thing:
why not split your database in a backend part (having all the tables) and a frontend part which contain the forms and tables the interns need? I'm guessing mostly it is going to be the same so you can even create multiple different frontend's to give to different interns incase they need other tables. There are a lot of articles out there about splitting a database and linking tables.

Then the thing about the record changes not sure is this is what your looking for but it could help, i haven't used it myself so not sure what it exacly does. But this may help you a bit. 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/197592

Answer (score 0):

I would consider taking a look at the BeforeUpdate event for the form.  You can trap the old and new values of textboxes if the form is bound to a table.  You could loop through all the controls on your form and check for Me.Control <> Me.Control.OldValue.  If they don't match, write both values to an auditing table so you can go back and check whenever you want to.  I would include the following fields in your auditing table:

- ChangeDate
- TableName
- ControlName
- OldValue
- NewValue

Then you can query that table any time you want to see what has changed.